# Failed to Initialize the encryption algorithm

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-authentication

I am using forms based authentication using Sql Memebership Provider and i have configure Sql Membership provider to use Encrypted password format instead of Hashed.I have also copied same machine key in all web.config files like application,central and STS.Now when i try to open infopath form i am getting error called Failed to Initialize the encryption algorithm but if i user password format Hashed and clear then its working file.am i missing some configuration ?

please advise

Thanks 
Ronak

Comment: Why not just use Hashed? It's more secure than Encrypted.  The only reason I can think of to use encrypted is if you have to retrieve the user's actual password - which IMHO is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks Chris.now we are using Hashed Password format and client is agree to do that too.